# iOS Swift WebView stop virtual Keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, virtual-keyboard

My iOS Swift App loads an UIWebView.

If the Users taps into the WebView, the first time after loading the WebView, the
Keyboard shows up.

It doesnt matter where the User Taps.

How can I prevent the Keyboard from opening in that case?

Comment: please check in your code have you ever written anywhere like becomeFirstResponder.

Comment: no nothing like that..